# cassandra cqlsh giving wrong counts

Tags: cassandra

I have a table in cassandra with only 2 columns and 16 rows. When I do a

```
select * from <table name>
```

I can see only 15 rows. 
When I do a

```
select count(*) from <table name>
```

I get count as 15
I am writing these queries in cqlsh
There is 1 row missing, but if I do something like select * from  where appname = '' I get the row.

When I am doing the samething using nodejs casandra driver I get the right result as 16. 
what can be the issue here. I did nodetool flush as well but same result
I am using cassandra 2.18

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be a problem of consistency level. The read consistency level to use depends on the replication factor and the write consistency level.

You can find more information about consistency level on [datastax documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html).

To quickly resolve your issue, you can try this on cqlsh :

```
CONSISTENCY ALL
SELECT count(*) ON <table name>
```

Comment: cqlsh is a client I quess and so it should be giving me data as per the drivers right?

Comment: Cqlsh is a client, so it behaves like the driver. But you are not exactly right saying that it should be giving the same data. The reason of this is  [Eventual Consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). Two identical queries can give you different data depending on which node is querried, with wich CL, and how much the data had been updated. If you are a beginner you should use QUORUM in writing and reading for you to do not bother much about consistency. Cqlsh default consistency level is ONE (which is low). Do you know what is your driver consistency level ?

Comment: This is an awesome explanation. I looked at the link and understood what it is. I am using Nodejs connector for cassandra from datastax  and using default consistency level which is ONE itself. Probably they are querying different machine.